# Why my content does not go to the right side of the screen?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am designing an admin dashboard. I thought of dividing the page into two parts by using the bootstrap grid system. One part (the 3/12 of the screen) includes a nav and that is OK but I want to put some content into the 9/12 of the screen and for some reason it is also appearing in the nav. I want the text "bruh" in the first picture to be in the purple place in the second picture.

[the current situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jakg0.png)
[how I want the things to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mk2jD.png)

This is my html code:

```
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 awesome_border">
                    <ul class="nav flex-column gotodown">
                        <li class="nav-item coolbox">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Stats</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item coolbox">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Graphs</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item coolbox">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Users</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                    <br>

                    <ul class="nav flex-column gotodown boxbox">
                        <li class="nav-item coolbox">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Reports</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item coolbox">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Revenue</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item coolbox">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Countries</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item coolbox">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Spammers</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>    
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-10">
                <ul class="nav flex-column">
                    <li class="nav-item"><h2>Bruh</h2></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

and this is my css:

```
body{
    font-family: 'Rosario', sans-serif;
    min-height: max-content;
}

.gotodown{
    margin-top: 80px;
    margin-left: 25px;
}

.coolbox{
    padding: 0.2em;
}

.boxbox{
    padding-top: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.awesome_border{
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: red;
}
```

I tried writing my content in the , expecting it to appear on the right side of the screen but it appeared in the nav to the left instead.

Answer (score 1):

You've got one unnecessary `div` and you're closing the `row div` too soon.

This works for me:

```
   <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 awesome_border">
                    <ul class="nav flex-column gotodown">
                        <li class="nav-item coolbox">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Stats</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item coolbox">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Graphs</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item coolbox">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Users</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                    <br>

                    <ul class="nav flex-column gotodown boxbox">
                        <li class="nav-item coolbox">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Reports</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item coolbox">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Revenue</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item coolbox">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Countries</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item coolbox">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Spammers</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>    
        
            <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-10">
                <ul class="nav flex-column">
                    <li class="nav-item"><h2>Bruh</h2></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Now you just need to implement some styling to get it positioned how you want.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any specification to align text/ content to the right

try this ***code example*** in your HTML for anything you want to send to the right be images or text.
put it in a div  `<div style="text-align: right;"><img src="myimage.jpg" width="100" alt="My Image" /></div>`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).